# Disabling checkbox in jquery grid

Tags: jquery

I am trying to disable a check box in a jggrid when the email ID is null. `email ID` is one of the column in the grid.
So,I am looping through the rows of the grid and checking if the email ID is null and trying the below code to disable check box

```
$jq("td[id=columnid] input").attr("disabled",true);
```

But it is disabling the entire column. I want to disable the cell of a row which has empty email. Please help

Thanks in Advance,
Nikhila

Comment: It would help if you showed some code

Comment: You need to show the structure of your html to get answers. Your question is not very clear.

Comment: `$jq("td[id=columnid] input[value='']").attr("disabled",true);`